# xhost and Pyautogui to click the buttons on a linux Application, cannot see mouse click action

Tags: python, linux, display, pyautogui

I have a Linux application, which automatically runs and loads on system startup, filling the entire display. Currently, I want to write a Python script to simulate mouse clicks on buttons within the application. Here is the issue I am facing: I connect to my Linux machine using SSH and use the PyAutoGUI library to simulate clicks. Previously, I manually entered the commands `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and `xhost +SI:localuser:root` in the terminal, followed by the command `sudo python3 XXX.py` to run the clicking script.And everthing goes well.

Now, I want to include the `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and `xhost +SI:localuser:root` commands within the same script. The code is as follows:

```
import os
import subprocess

try:
    # Set DISPLAY variable
    os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ":0.0"

    # Execute xhost command
    subprocess.run(["xhost", "+SI:localuser:root"], shell=False)

  
    # Continue with PyAutoGUI operations
 
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f'Error configuring environment: {e}')

# Rest of  PyAutoGUI script
```

At this point, I encounter an issue. The message '**localuser:root being added to access control list**' is printed in the terminal, but I do not see the mouse click operations. When the script finishes running, executing `echo $DISPLAY` does not show my configured **:0.0**, but rather 10.0. How can I resolve this problem? I mean no click action when set the DISPLAY and xhost+ with the Python script.
Hope someone can give comments here, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, run the following commands `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and `xhost +SI:localuser:root` in the terminal, then `sudo python3 XXX.py`, with above steps, I can see the mouse clicking the buttons on APP. But the issue is when I put `os.environ['DISPLAY'] =":0.0"` and `subprocess.run(["xhost", "+SI:localuser:root"], shell=False)` in python script, and in the terminal run `sudo python3 XXX.py` directly, then the mouse doesnot click the buttons.

Comment: Can you try to put `import pyautogui` after `try ... except` ?

Comment: @Philippe That worked!!